# Is it possible to set debug points for Java and Objective-C with Visual Studio Cordova?

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to figure out a way to debug native Java and Objective-C code for a Cordova plugin, and I was wondering if it is possible to use Visual Studio Cordova to do this on my Mac. Ideally, I would like to hit these debug points at runtime. I have seen videos and other tutorials showing that it is possible to set debug points in JavaScript, which is helpful, but not what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I'm guessing that this is not currently possible as only Visual Studio Code is available on Mac. I gather that Visual Studio Community or Enterprise is needed to use Visual Studio Cordova. I also assume that Visual Studio can not debug Objective-C yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately neither Java nor Objective-C debugging is supported by Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova today.

Cordova generates a native Android and iOS project under the hood (which I am guessing you know given you're doing plugin development). VS can be used to generate the underlying Android or iOS project, but you'll need to use native tools to debug Java or Objective-C.  If you're using the "remotebuild" agent, you can find the generated Xcode projects under ~/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds.